# Making the middle of a ring transparent using CSS

Tags: css, react-native

What I am trying to accomplish is have a similar button we find within the iPhone record.

What I currently have as seen in the picture below is a ring but isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

What I am hoping to accomplish is a ring outer later, with some transparent (see background when moving camera around) then a red dot.

Was hoping some advice since I'm unable to use transparent as it would just take on the color from the container which is white.

**CODE**

```
                        <View
                            style={{
                                borderRadius: 40,
                                width: 80,
                                height: 80,
                                backgroundColor: 'white',
                                overflow: 'hidden'
                            }}
                        >
                            <View
                                style={{
                                    borderRadius: 35,
                                    width: 70,
                                    height: 70,
                                    margin: 5,
                                    backgroundColor: 'black'
                                }}
                            >
                                <Text>HELLO</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce that output using Stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
  <View
    style={{
        borderRadius: 40,
        borderWidth: 2,
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        borderColor: 'white',
        overflow: 'hidden'
    }}
  >
    <View
        style={{
            borderRadius: 35,
            width: 70,
            height: 70,
            margin: 5,
        }}
    >
      <Text>HELLO</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```